# Copy HTML file with respective folder automatic

Tags: cmd

I m facing problem regarding to copy html file respective folder automatic, it was works till day before yesterday, But I tried to copy file & folder using CMD command & after that not working.

I was tried below code

```
copy "C:\Test\AIR AND FLUE GAS SYSTEM1.htm" "C:\Test\Done\AIR AND FLUE GAS SYSTEM1.htm"
Xcopy "C:\Test\AIR AND FLUE GAS SYSTEM1_files" "C:\Test\Done\AIR AND FLUE GAS SYSTEM1_files" /s
```

But now if I copy html file then only copy selected file, but before that respective folder was also copied.

Comment: Not able to understand the last part 'But now if I copy html file then only selected file copy, but earliest respective folder also copy.'

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to use `/s` not `\s`

Comment: Ya it's \S, typo mistake

Answer (score 0):

if this doesn't work for you then show us the error message.

```
copy "C:\Test\AIR AND FLUE GAS SYSTEM1.htm" "C:\Test\Done\"
Xcopy "C:\Test\AIR AND FLUE GAS SYSTEM1_files\*.*" "C:\Test\Done\AIR AND FLUE GAS SYSTEM1_files\" /s
```